# Draw only the border of scatter plot in Matlab

Tags: matlab, scatter-plot

I have a bunch of 2 dimensional vectors in Matlab. If I plot them in two dimension space using scatter they fill an area which is not convex. Is there ay way to simply draw only the border of the area? I have tried `hist` plus `contour` or `convex hull` but they do not do the job.

Comment: `convexHull()` (https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/delaunaytriangulation.convexhull.html) seems like the answer to your question. Could you please include your code for that attempt?

Answer (score 0):

From matlab help:

```
x = gallery('uniformdata',[10,1],0);
y = gallery('uniformdata',[10,1],1);
DT = delaunayTriangulation(x,y);
k = convexHull(DT)
figure
plot(DT.Points(:,1),DT.Points(:,2), '.','markersize',10);
hold on
plot(DT.Points(k,1),DT.Points(k,2),'r') 
hold off
```